# Should I add a radius for max radius call in a diagram when creating a 3D CAD?

Tags: metallurgy, technical-drawing

If on a blueprint it says `XXXX R. Max.` do I need to add a radius when creating a CAD representation, or is the radius always optional, but if present must not exceed the max value?

[image]

Comment: If you're asking about whether to represent it in the 3D model: if R=0 is allowable, probably not. At least for machine-parts drawings, architectural/structural practice may differ